# I am 19 years old in USA in J1 visa. I got a job offer, should I apply for green-card?

Tags: usa, residency

I came to the US a couple of months ago on a J1 visa. I am a professional freelance developer and have had three clients within three years. I got a job offer, but couldn't find out what the next step is. Can I apply for green card if this might be my permanent job?

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Make sure your J-1 doesn't have a 2-year home residency requirement, because if it does, you cannot get permanent residency until you've been physically present in your home country for at least 2 years after your J-1.

Comment: J-1 is not a dual intent visa. If you apply for a Green Card and your application is denied, your J-1 may become invalid. So you might want to talk with a lawyer about your chances of getting a Green Card and risks involved.

Comment: As I understand, getting an employment-based Green Card without a college degree or very extensive work experience is nearly impossible.

Comment: @user102008 No I am not subjected to section 212e

Answer (score 2):

If they're willing to sponsor you for a green card (which would be the best thing), then yes; however, it's usually H status you have to convert to.

Keep in mind, if you Switch to H status, then next time you travel abroad, you must get an H visa at the US embassy before re-entering the US. All paperwork pertaining to the employment should be brought for this.